# feature branch got master commits after merge

Tags: git, github, git-merge

So I have a `master` branch and `feature/123-branch`.

I was on `feature/123-branch` with `git checkout feature/123-branch` and noticed it was out of date with `master` so I did

`git merge master` to keep up-to-date.

Before the `merge` the `feature/123-branch` had just `2 commits` that I did to develop the feature, but when I did

`git push origin feature/123-branch`

the number of commits jumped to like `40` due to merge (I think?).

I tried a `rebase --onto master HEAD~1 feature/123-branch` but it didn't do anything to fix the situation.

How can I go back to having just the `2 commits` on my `feature/123-branch` by keeping it up-to-date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you had something like this:

```
M0-M1-M2-M3-M4-...-MX  (master)
     \
      F0-F1            (feature branch)
```

and you wanted to "keep up-to-date" by making it like so:

```
M0-M1-M2-M3-M4-...-MX         (master)
                    \
                     F0'-F1'  (feature branch)
```

with commits `F0'` and `F1'` being commits `F0` and `F1` (the commits from your feature branch), but altered slightly so that the changes take place after the last commit on `master`

If that is what you wanted to do, then what you intended to do wasn't merging `master`  and your feature branch, but rebasing your feature branch on master.

In that case, here's how to do it:

1. `git checkout feature/123-branch` to make sure you're in your feature branch
2. `git log` to list the latest commits on that branch, and find the hash corresponding to F1
3. `git reset --hard the_hash_from_F1` to roll back the merge
4. `git rebase master` to do what you had intended to do in the first place and "update" your branch

Comment: I was in the process of writing about the same, you beat me to it. (+1)